# word 2007 to pdf conversion version 7 or less

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I have to convert some Word files to pdf version 7 or earlier for an administrative application that requires us to upload only pdf 7- docs. 
The thing is, I have Word 2007 and I don't know how to save files to pdf with a specified version. I mean I know I should do "Save as..." + PDF but how can I specify the pdf version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that is an option in Word.  However, that is possible by installing a third-party application:

1. Install BullZip PDF Printer.
2. Print the Word document via the Bullzip PDF Printer.
3. A dialog box will pop up asking where you would like to save the file.
4. Before clicking OK to save the file, go to the Document tab.
5. In the Compatibility Level dropdown, choose PDF 1.6 (Acrobat 7.x)
6. Adjust other options if needed, and click OK to save the file; and-- Voila!